# How to dynamically weight sensor output

Tags: calculus, probability, analysis

**Goal**

I would like to combine the output of 7 sensor (which all have a different sensitivity range) into one output value.

**Layout**

I have a setup where I over time measure light intensity from 7 different angles with a sensor. I also have calibrated measurement that is the ‘real’ light intensity.

The data looks like this:

```
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|            | sensor1 | sensor2 | sensor3 | sensor4 | sensor5 | sensor6 | sensor7 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
| Real value |         |         |         |         |         |         |         |
| 0.037      |     258 |     496 |     249 |     197 |     151 |     143 |     173 |
| 0.113      |    1105 |     709 |     427 |     255 |     172 |     162 |     230 |
| 0.343      |     887 |     562 |     415 |     351 |     322 |     420 |     650 |
| 0.45       |     857 |     555 |     452 |     457 |     502 |     756 |    1194 |
| 0.61       |     870 |     561 |     465 |     483 |     546 |     838 |    1318 |
| 0.676      |     883 |     579 |     488 |     523 |     608 |     955 |    1503 |
| 0.77       |     887 |     581 |     493 |     539 |     639 |    1012 |    1588 |
+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

[visualized table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7Q3n.png)

**Background**

Using scipy’s [curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), I can get a good description using an inverse 4-parameter sigmoid function.

```
RealValue = c*np.power((a-d)/(MeasuredValue-d)-1,(1/b))
```

See [first row of plots in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV0XI.png). I can also calculate the  errors on the parameters (a,b,c,d) and use that to visualize the variation of the fits (dotted lines)

However I don’t really know what kind of mathematics I need to dynamically weight the contribution of 
each curve fitted function. I end up with 4 times (the other 3 sensors do not respond well) an inverse 4-parameter sigmoid function, but how do I combine those?

I came across [Sensor fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sensor_fusion), but this did not yield any concrete examples except for the [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter). But a Kalman filter does not seem to be relevant, since I can get a good estimate using the inverse 4-parameter sigmoid functions.

I thought of calculating the 1st order derivate of the inverse 4-parameter sigmoid function ([second row of plots in this figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lV0XI.png)) and then using the inverse of the 1st order derivative as a weighting factor for each sensor depending on their output value. Because the 1st order derivate encodes how well a change in the real value is reflected in the measured value. 
Does this make sense? Or am I missing a completely obvious solution to dynamically weigh these functions?

Comment: What do you mean by "dynamically"?

Comment: Depending on the output of the sensors. Say sensor7 is more sensitive in the 1000-2000 range and sensor1 is more sensitive in the 0-1000 range. When the output value of sensor1 is 700 and sensor7 is 900 its contribution of sensor1 should be weighing in more than that of sensor7. Does that make sense?

Comment: I see. I think it does.